# Can reading garbage memory break program flow?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, linked-list, heap-corruption

In my application, I have a nested pair of loops which follow similarly-nested linked lists in order to parse the data. I made a stupid blunder and cast one struct as the child struct, EG:

```
if (((ENTITY *) OuterEntityLoop->data)->visible == true) {
```

instead of:

```
if (((ENTITY_RECORD *) OuterEntityLoop->data)->entity->visible == true) {
```

This caused a problem where about 70% of runs would result in the application halting completely - not crashing, just sitting and spinning. Diagnostic `printf`s in program flow would fire in odd order or not at all, and though it spontaneously recovered a couple of times for the most part it broke the app.

So here's the thing. Even after paring down the logic inside to be absolutely it wasn't infinite looping based on a logic bug, to the point where the loop *only* contained my `printf`, it was still broken.

Thing two: when the struct was identified incorrectly, it still complained if I tried to access a nonexistent property even though it didn't have the *extant* property.

My questions are:

1. Why did this corrupt memory? Can simply *reading* garbage memory trash the program's control structures? If not, does this mean I still have a leak somewhere even though Electric Fence doesn't complain anymore?
2. I assume that the reason it complained about a nonexistent property is because it goes by the type definition given, not what's actually there. This is less questionable in my mind now that I've typed it out, but I'd like confirmation that I'm not off base here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no telling what will happen when a program accesses invalid memory, even for reading.  On some systems, any memory read operation will either be valid or cause an immediate program crash, but on other systems it's possible that an erroneous read could be misinterpreted as a signal to do something.  You didn't specify whether you're using a PC or an embedded system, but on embedded systems there are often many addresses by design which trigger various actions when they are read [e.g. dequeueing received data from a serial port, or acknowledging an interrupt]; an erroneous read of such an address might cause serial data to be lost, or might cause the interrupt controller to think an interrupt had been processed when it actually hadn't.

Further, in some embedded systems, an attempt to read an invalid address may have other even worse effects that aren't really by design, but rather by happenstance.  On one system I designed, for example, I had to interface a memory device which was a little slow to get off the bus following a read cycle.  Provided that the next memory read was performed from a memory area which had at least one wait sate or was on a different bus, there would be no problem.  If code which was running in the fast external memory partition tried to read that area, however, the failure of the memory device to get off the bus quickly would corrupt some bits of the next fetched instruction.  The net effect of all this was that accessing the slow device from code located in some places was no problem, but accessing it--intentionally or not--from code located in the fast partition would cause weird and non-reproduceable failures.

Comment: It was on a Linux desktop, so definitely not embedded. Not to say your answer was any less interesting for that, though - I really enjoyed the anecdote. :)

Comment: @sudowned: I thought it was a nice example of how the "undefined behavior" resulting from an invalid memory read really does mean essentially *anything* can happen.  I'm not sure why an x86-based Linux box would behave particularly oddly as a consequence of a stray read, though I can imagine some possibilities.  An OS which lazily allocates stack space might interpret a stray memory access as a request to expand the stack.  Depending on what validation it does, such stack expansion may collide with other allocated storage.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to C, where the power of casting, allows you to make any piece of memory look like any object you want, but at your own risk.  If the thing you cast is not really an object of that type, and that type contains a pointer to something else, you run the risk of crashing.  Since even attempting to read random memory that has not been actually mapped into a processes virtual memory address space can cause a core or reading from the certain areas of memory that do not have read permission will also cause a core, like the NULL pointer.

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct bar
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct foo *p;
};

void evil_cast(void *p)
{
    /* hmm... maybe this is a bar pointer */
    struct bar *q = (struct bar *)p;
    if (q != NULL) /* q is some valid pointer */
    {
        /* as long as q points readable memory q->x will return some value, */
        /* this has a fairly high probability of success */
        printf("random pointer to a bar, x value x(%d)\n", q->x);
        /* hmm... lets use the foo pointer from my random bar */
        if (q->p != NULL)
        {
            /* very high probabilty of coring, since the likely hood that a */
            /* random piece of memory contains a valid address is much lower */
            printf("random value of x from a random foo pointer, from a random bar pointer x value x(%d)\n", q->p->x);
        }

     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *random_heap_data = (int *)malloc(1024); /* just random head memory */
    /* setup the first 5 locations to be some integers */
    random_heap_data[0] = 1;
    random_heap_data[1] = 2;
    random_heap_data[2] = 3;
    random_heap_data[3] = 4;
    random_heap_data[4] = 5;
    evil_cast(random_heap_data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the application didn't crash (until I linked in Electric Fence.) The loop stopped running when the garbage memory was read - I know because the debug text stopped echoing to console - but the OS didn't kill it.

Comment: Sometimes you get luckly when accessing memory from a mis-typecast pointer, but as they say "your mileage may vary".